# Utility to batch extract images from a thumbs.db thumbnail database

Tags: windows, thumbnails, thumbs.db

I've found a few thumbnail *viewer* tools, but nothing that can simply **open a thumbs.db file and spit out a directory full of images** (GIF, JPG, PNG, what have you) contained inside.

Tried ThumbsExtract, but keep getting "couldn't open stream!" errors on every file.

Pointers?

Comment: helpful link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_thumbnail_cache

Answer (score 1):

[Vinetto](http://vinetto.sourceforge.net/#Usage) looks good:

```
 % python vinetto -o thumbs thumbs.db
```

it is a python script, it should work under win32. at the moment the site states that you would need cygwin, but when quickly glancing over the code thats just .. easy to fix and i quite honestly dont understand why it is written the way it is written.

Answer (score 0):

[Thumbnail Database Viewer](http://www.itsamples.com/thumbnail-database-viewer.html) can open a thumbs.db file and save the images one-by-one.
I tried it and it seems to work.

Another such product is [ThumbsUp](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/hvogt/proj/thumbsup/), which promises to extract more than one image at a time, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Thumbnail Database Viewer has a decent UI, but I have ~9,000 images I need, so one-by-one isn't an option :)

Tried ThumbsUp, but couldn't get anywhere with the Java/Apache/POI dependency mess.